# how to fetch querystring from url in our form using javascript

Tags: javascript

I submitted form using Get method now the data is shown in query string now I want to fetch value of it in another form.

how to do it using

Comment: please complete your question 'using..??'

Answer (score 0):

In the second form, you can access it using this -

```
$_GET('yourVariableNameInPreviousForm');
```

Answer (score 0):

**User following function:**

```
function getQueryStringValue(name) {
name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
    results = regex.exec(location.search);
return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

**USES:**

```
var queryStringValue = getQueryStringValue("ID")
```